# C# Can i Extend the IdentityMessage from the EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

(using the  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity)

The IdentityMessage message within the EmailService has 3 properties

```
public virtual string Body { get; set; }
public virtual string Destination { get; set; }
public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
```

When you only have 1 "from" adress it is enough, but if you want more then one "from" address, it is a problem and I need the extra property.

```
public string From { get; set; }
```

So I extended the class IdentityMessage (like I dit with Users and roles)

```
public class ExtendedMessage : IdentityMessage
{
    public string From { get; set; }
}
```

So I changed the default implementation

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        await configSMTPasync(message);
    }

    // send email via smtp service
    private async Task configSMTPasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // SEND MAIL
    }
}
```

With

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(ExtendedMessage message)
    {
        await configSMTPasync(message);
    }

    // send email via smtp service
    private async Task configSMTPasync(ExtendedMessage message)
    {
        // SEND MAIL
    }
}
```

But IIdentityMessageService is still refering to the original IdentityMessage (it is not working as espected)

What is the best way to get this working (using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; framework)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into ClaimsIdentity, it has a Dictionary, and you can add whatever properties you would like to add.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar issue and managed to find a way around it. I was trying to pass Cc'd recipients to the function.

So there's no way to extend the function input paramters for 'SendAsync' withing IIdentityMessageService due to it having strong type paramter of 'IdentityMessage'. Inheriting IdentityMessage on any derived class would not work due to the strong type function signature.

```
//
// Summary:
// Expose a way to send messages (i.e. email/sms)
public interface IIdentityMessageService
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     This method should send the message
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   message:
    Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message);
}
```

I opted to do the following. Note, my solution might not be the best solution, but it's the only one I could do in the timeframe I had.

1st, I created my own interface named 'IEmailService', and inherited 'IIdentityMessageService' on it. I then implemented my own method for 'SendAsync' to create a additional override for the function.

```
internal interface IEmailService: IIdentityMessageService
{
    Task SendAsync(string destination, string subject, string body, List<string> ccRecipients);
}
```

2nd, I created my email service and implemented code for both the function signatures. The implementation of the code within 'SendAsync' is up to you. You can do what you like.

```
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // code for mailing
    }

    public Task SendAsync(string destination, string subject, string body, List<string> ccRecipients)
    {
        // code for mailing
    }
}
```

3rd, Within 'ApplicationUserManager' class, within the 'Create' function. I instantiated a instance of my 'EmailService' and assigned it to the 'EmailService' property of 'ApplicationUserManager'.

```
applicationUserManager.EmailService = new EmailService();
```

4th, So the 'ApplicationUserManager' should inherit UserManager<TUser, TKey>.
You can then override the 'virtual async Task SendEmailAsync' within the 'ApplicationUserManager' class or you could just go ahead and create a new 'CustomSendEmailAsync' function. Regardless of what you do, it should just pass whatever additional params you're looking for. Example below.

```
public override async Task SendEmailAsync(int userId, string subject, string body)
{
        User userFound = this.FindById(userId);
        if (userFound == null)
            throw new Exception("Mail service was not able to identify user.");

        List<string> ccRecipients = new List<string>();
            if (userFound.SecondaryEmail != null)
                ccRecipients.Add(userFound.SecondaryEmail);

        await (base.EmailService as IEmailService).SendAsync(userFound.Email, subject, body, ccRecipients);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use inheritance because once entity is loaded from the data source EF will not know about inheritance and because of that it will instantiate base type without your properties instead of derived type with your properties. Any inheritance must be mapped in EDMX if EF have to work with it.

Using partial class will solve your problem but:

All parts of partial class must be defined in the same assembly
Properties from your partial part are not persisted to the database
Properties from your partial part cannot be used in linq-to-entities queries